# First remapping two keys separately and then their combo to third key

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking to remap my two function volume keys SC130 and SC12E like this:

- SC130 while held down alone: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
- SC12E while held down alone: <kbd>ALT</kbd>
- SC130 + SC12E held down together: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (no <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>)

What is the most elegant way to accomplish this? I've tried different approaches, but can't get it to work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SC130 & SC12E::Send, {Shift Down}
SC130 & SC12E Up::Send, {Shift up}
SC130::Send, {Ctrl}
SC12E::Send, {Alt}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This seems to work partially, but still not completely. (shift works, but both buttons won't work separately while holding). I also tried this:

`SC130 & SC12E::Send, {Shift down}
SC130 Up & SC12E Up::Send, {Shift up}

SC130::Ctrl
SC12E::Alt`

But for some reason the &-line swallows the other line `SC130::Ctrl`. Alt works. There's something fishy still going on, I think it might be that they both get triggered if I don't press them absolutely simultaneously (which is hard).

How could I fix this?